# what is wrong with this while loop construct?

Tags: python, printing, while-loop

what is wrong with this loop construct:

```
x=0
y=1
while (y!=0):
   x,y=y+1,x+1
   print(x)
```

Is it that it is a never ending loop? that it just keeps printing a value for `x`, since there isn't a specified domain?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: what is a specified domain? and what do you think `y!=0` means?

Comment: when y is not equal to 0

Comment: also can anyone tell me what type v=(-68!=42*-1), will it be a float or what? when i write type(v) in python it given be boolean is that a suitable answer? that v is boolean type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it. It does what you told it to do. It loops as long as `y` is not equal to zero. And since you start with `y = 1` and increase it in every iteration, the loop keeps going on forever.

```
                   before    after
                     x  y     x  y
1st iteration        0  1     2  1
2nd iteration        2  1     2  3
3nd iteration        2  3     4  3
4th iteration        4  3     4  5
…
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your while condition is y != 0, and y = y + 1 means that y will be bigger, bigger. 
It will never hit 0 because by default integers in python are long long